# './App' does not contain a default exportが出てしまう

Tags: reactjs

エラー内容
Unexpected token, expected "," (127:0)

こちらのエラーでコンパイルできずにいます。初歩的な質問かと思いますが、どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

````
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifySignUp, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Bucket } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [file, setFile] = useState('')
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('')

    const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState();
    const [s3Objects, setS3Objects] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      AWS.config.update({
        region: 'ap-northeast-1',
        accessKeyId: 'キー',
        secretAccessKey: 'キー'})
      const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
      var bucketParams = {
        Bucket : 'バケット',
        };
    s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        setS3Objects(data.Contents); // setS3Objectsを呼ぶことで再度レンダリングが行われる。
      }
        return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
            setAuthState(nextAuthState);
            setUser(authData)
        });
    }, []);

    const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (e.target.files[0] !== null) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0])
      setName(e.target.files[0].name)
    }
  }
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (file) {
      Storage.put(name, file, {
        /* level: 'protected', */
        contentType: file.type,
      })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          setResponse(`Success uploading file: ${name}!`)
        })
        .then(() => {
          document.getElementById('file-input').value = null
          setFile(null)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
          setResponse(`Can't upload file: ${err}`)
        })
    } else {
      setResponse(`Files needed!`)
    }
  }
  
s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
  console.log("Error", err);
} else {
  for (let i= 0;i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
    list1.push(data.Contents[i]);
    console.log(data.Contents[i].Key); //これもコンソールに出力される
  }
  for(var d in list1){
    console.log(list1[d].Key);　//これもコンソールに出力される
  } 
}
})
    return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
      <div className="App">
          <div>Hello, {user.username}</div>
          <div className='video-uploader'>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <p>
              <label className='select-label'>Select video: </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input
                className='video-input'
                type='file'
                id='file-input'
                accept='image/*, video/*'
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              />
            </p>
            <button type='submit' className='btn'>Submit</button>
          </form>
          <div><div>
      {s3Objects.map((o) => <p>{o.Key}</p>)}
    </div>
          </div>
          
          </div>
            
          <AmplifySignOut />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <AmplifyAuthenticator>
        <AmplifySignUp
          slot="sign-up"
          formFields={[
            { type: "username" },
            { type: "password" },
            { type: "email" }
          ]}
        />
      </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
}

export default App;```


コメントにより解決しました。
````

Comment: `React.useEffect(() => ...` が閉じていないですね(paren mismatch)。エディタかIDEのフォーマッタを使ってインデントを調整してみると判るかと思います。

Comment: 有難うございます。閉じていませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

凡ミスによるコンパイルエラーでした。解決しました。有難うございました。